# Iptables round-robin through multiple virtual network interfaces

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, policy-routing, round-robin

I have a server with two main network interfaces and 5 virtual interfaces like this.

```
eth0 - 192.168.1.1
eth1 - 192.168.3.1

eth1:2 192.168.3.3
eth1:3 192.168.3.4
eth1:4 192.168.3.5
eth1:5 192.168.3.6
eth1:6 192.168.3.7
```

etho is my internal facing interface and eth1 is my external facing interface. I need to route all my traffic using all 5 network interfaces using round robin. if three request come to the eth0 those three requests go through the eth1:1 eth1:2 eth 1:3 respectively. order is not matter. i need to use all five interfaces active and routing  my traffic using round robin. how Can I do this ? is it possible to do with iptables only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do this using the `PREROUTING` chain with the statistic module.
You can look at this article : [Simple Stateful Load Balancer with iptables and NAT](https://www.webair.com/community/simple-stateful-load-balancer-with-iptables-and-nat/)

In your case it could be something like :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode random
 --probability .25 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.3

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode random
 --probability .25 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.4

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode random
 --probability .25 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.5

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode random
 --probability .25 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.6
```

It should work theoretically, but I can't assure you that this setup will work with stateful protocols

Another option could be to look for a solution such as [HAPROXY](http://www.haproxy.org)